# Using Multiple Sics in One Quote

Tags: quotes

If a quote is rife with errors, can a single [sic] be used at the end of the quote rather than after each error?

She wrote, "Your [sic] making me weigh [sic] to [sic] sleepy."

She wrote, "Your making me weigh to sleepy [sic]."

Answer (score 7):

You should use *[sic]* after each mistake, in case you introduce a new mistake.

For example, let's say we use the text you've used:

> Your making me weigh to sleepy.

If we misspell *making*,

> Your [sic] mkaing me weigh [sic] to [sic] sleepy.

We show that the misspelling was introduced by the quoter.

On the other hand, if we do

> Your mkaing me weigh to sleepy [sic].

It attributes the misspelling to the quotee.

Comment: How does placing [sic] at the very end attribute the misspelling to the quotee? I was under the impression that [sic] meant that the entire quoted passage is the same as in the original source.

Comment: @Mana That's correct. I'm introducing a hypothetical example where in quoting the text, we add a fourth error by misspelling "making", which is spelled correctly in the original case. That's the editor's fault, not the fault of the original person who wrote it, so by not placing a [sic] there, readers know that the orignal author of the horrible text was just a tiny fraction less of an idiot.

Comment: Ah, missed that. I am dumb and can't read and also mixed up quotee and quoter.

Comment: I don't see any sense in the idea that you put [sic] after every word *known to be erroneous* just so any errors *not* thus flagged can be recognised as later ones made by the current writer. We don't adopt conventions in the expectation of making mistakes. I would just put [sic] *after* the full stop, letting it apply to the whole sentence.

Comment: Would it be acceptable if I simply correct the spelling?